# Prove complex function is not holomorphic using definition (without Cauchy-Riemann equations)

Tags: complex-analysis, definition, holomorphic-functions

I'm just starting to learn complex analysis and currently reading the book "Complex analysis" by Stein and Shakarchi.

Since the fact of the function being ***holomorphic*** appears to be pretty important, I'm starting with it.

Here's the definition:
The function $f$ is holomorphic at the point $z_0 \in \Omega$ if the quotient $$\frac{f(z_0+h)-f(z_0)}{h}$$ converges to a limit when
$h \to 0$.

Then we are given two examples. First of the function $f(z)=z$ being holomorphic on any open set in $\Bbb C$, and $f'(z) = 1$. And second of the function $f(z)=\bar z$ being ***not holomorphic***.

While I think I understand first example, I cannot see how the second will be different, how the fact of the *complex conjugate* changes the set up? Basically, why $f(z)=\bar z$ is not holomorphic by definition? 
I am aware of the Cauchy-Riemann equations, but I want to see the proof based on the definition (especially that the fact is claimed at this point in the book).

I tried to search for an answer but didn't find anything particularly related. I also think I might miss some very basic concept. With all that said I will really appreciate your input.

Comment: I had this same concern. Instead of just testing the CR equations, try using them from first principles and setting up the limit definitions with $\overline{z}$ specifically. It helped me, anyway.

Comment: @TheCount Thanks for the comment! I'm not sure if I completely understoo it, but from what I did :) I'd say that the goal was really to look at this problem as if I had no idea about CR equations.

Comment: that's exactly what I meant. I hope it helped!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A good rule of thumb for complex analysis is that, if something has gone wrong, $0$ is almost certainly to blame.

Here is the difference quotient for $\overline{z}$ at $0$ taken along two different paths in the complex plane:

Tending to $0$ along the positive imaginary axis produces:

$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\overline{\left(0+ih\right)}-\overline{0}}{ih}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{-ih}{ih}=-1$

On the other hand, tending to $0$ along the positive *real* axis produces:

$\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{\overline{\left(0+h\right)}-\overline{0}}{h}=\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{h}{h}=1$

which is completely different. Since the limits do not agree, the limit of this difference quotient as $h$ tends to $0$ in $\mathbb{C}$ does not exist. Thus, the conjugate function is not complex differentiable at $0$.

Generally, when working "from first principles" as it were, one has to rely on the two-dimensionality of $\mathbb{C}$ (along with its algebraic/"arithmetic" properties) to show that things are different than the case of single real-variable analysis. Indeed, it is exactly because the condition of holomorphy requires these two-dimensional limits to exist that holomorphic functions are so marvelously well-behaved (in stark contrast to functions of multiple real variables).

Comment: This is exactly the kind of explanation I was looking for, thank you very much!

Comment: Happy to hear so, and am glad to have been helpful. :)

Comment: Indeed I missed the basic thing: for some reason I was considering $f(\bar z_0 + h)$ and not $f(\overline {{z_0 + h}})$

Comment: I *really* like this answer, and I will save it in my mental back pocket.

Answer (score 2):

Long comment about problems like that ("prove that ... isn't complex differentiable without using C-R").

Let be $c = a + bi$. It's easy to see that the condition
$$\exists \lim_{z\to c}\frac{f(z) - f(c)}{z - c}$$
is equivalent to "$f$ considered as function of two real variables is $\Bbb R$-differentiable at $(a,b)$ and the differential is $\Bbb C$-linear". And differential being $\Bbb C$-linear $\iff$ C-R equations. Then, there are two possibilities for $f$ not being $\Bbb C$-differentiable at some point $c$:

- $f$ considered as function of two real variables isn't $\Bbb R$-differentiable at $(a,b)$: the $\Bbb R$-differential does not exists.
- $f$ considered as function of two real variables is $\Bbb R$-differentiable at $(a,b)$ but fails to verify the C-R equations: the $\Bbb R$-differential does exists but isn't $\Bbb C$-linear.

The examples usually seen (conjugation, modulus...) are $\Bbb R$-differentiable at (almost) every point but they do not satisfy C-R.

But what are the partial derivatives? *Limits in a subspace*. When we check that  $\lim_{z\to c}\frac{f(z) - f(c)}{z - c}$ does not exists finding that the limits in different subspaces are different (like in the other answer), *we are actually checking C-R*.

Bottom line: posing the problems of this type without clarification can mislead the students.